# Add Lucee Extensions in Docker For Windows using CommandBox

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, lucee, docker-desktop, commandbox

I'm trying to install `lucee` with **Docker Desktop for Windows** and CommandBox.. when i use command docker run, there is a lucee extension that not available which is ortus.extension.rediscache. How do I install this lucee extension so i can use it using Docker For Windows and CommandBox?

here is the error generated from lucee :

```
The OSGi Bundle with name [ortus.extension.rediscache] in version [1.0.0.00063] is not available locally (rootserverHomeWEB-INFlucee-serverbundles) or from the update provider (httprelease.lucee.org).
```

here is my command in docker :

```
docker run --env-file=development.env -p 8080:8080 -p 8443:8443 -v //d/project/we/dummy://app ortussolutions/commandbox
```

here is my development.env content :

```
CONFIGURATION_DB_CLASS=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
CONFIGURATION_DB_HOST=192.168.11.17
CONFIGURATION_DB_PORT=3306
CONFIGURATION_DB_DATABASE=database
CONFIGURATION_DB_USERNAME=user
CONFIGURATION_DB_PASSWORD=password
REDIS_HOST=localhost
REDIS_PORT=6379
SERVER_HOME_DIRECTORY=
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer.. i just have to open lucee server administrator and install the extension.. :D

Comment: That's not really an answer per se, just a work around.  You need to add a step to your docker image build that copies the extension into the deploy folder for Lucee's server context.  Have you purchased a license for the Ortus Redis Extension.  We provide installation support for this and can help you.  You'll also need to set up the licensing so it loads automatically as well.,